# What do you advice in order to test my Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, tdd

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and I am planning to switch to the versioni 3.1 as soon as possible. With the new RoR version I am planning also to add automated tests in my application.

1. **What do you advice in order to test my application?**
2. Do you advice some book to read and\or software to use?
3. If I start to write tests for RoR 3.0.10, those will be available and compatible in RoR 3.1?

In few words, I would like to know all about testing that I can, should and "must" use to improve my applications (*also* to test jQuery-JavaScript code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [Rspec 2](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec)
2. Use [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)
3. Use [Spork](https://github.com/timcharper/spork)
4. Use [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard)

Guard + Spork (+ Rspec + Capybara) = Automated Testing.

I don't recommend using Cucumber.  Everyone loves Cucumber, but it's a lot more work than it's worth.  It's a regular expression layer on top of what you can do very easily with Rspec + Capybara with [the new acceptance testing feature](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2011/acceptance-testing-using-capybaras-new-rspec-dsl/) (it was a separate gem, now it's included in rspec).

When you build your app, I recommend this:

1. As you're conceptualizing your **models**, write Rspec models test descriptions.  Things like `it "should save a :start_date"`.  Start building your models first by writing tests for the attributes (which `start_date` values it accepts, how to handle invalid values, etc.).  Then as needed, write integration tests between models.  They're *model* tests, not *unit* tests.  When you're writing tests for the model attributes, those are unit tests (isolated class tests).  When you're testing the functionality between models (when I do `user.posts.create(:title => "My first blog post")`, I expect a post is created for that user), those are in my opinion "integration" tests.  In Rspec, these are "model" tests.
2. After you get some basics of your models in, **write view tests**.  In order to implement the assertions in your view tests, you'll need to have Spork, Guard, and Capybara setup.  And then you'll need to write your Haml… and then your controller code…  In the end, you'll be writing the code to make the view test pass.  The idea of having both controller and view tests is overkill.  With Rspec + Capybara acceptance tests, you can wrap everything into the `spec/acceptance` directory.  Saves you time and lots of thought.  In the end you test your models thoroughly, and the requests/html thoroughly.
3. As your app gets larger, the tests will take much longer to run.  It can easily take 10-20 minutes to run all tests!  That'll quickly turn you off, especially if all you want is to just fix a typo before re-pushing.  To avoid this, figure out clever ways to use seed data (data you don't need to recreate between each test), or clever ways to use mock data, and setup Spork.  By not having to reload the Rails server between test runs, you cut out a TON of time.  And with Guard + Spork, you don't need Autotest (Autotest is outdated).
4. If you want to go a step further, you can then test your javascript.  This is still a very new area.  There are two approaches right now, 1) using Capybara with a javascript-enabled driver (selenium is the only one that really works as of this post), or 2) using [jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine).  I'd wait on this one, if your app is not a "purely javascript" app.

For Javascript tests, I'm thinking building [some sort of node.js/websocket layer](https://github.com/viatropos/see.js) that allows you to run jasmine tests locally against your Rails + Spork test server, on your Mac and Windows (via Parallels or VMWare Fusion or whatever), is a much better way to do view + javascript testing, because you get the whole app as it really is in production.

That's all you'll need as of now to build a solid Rails app.  Hope that helps, Lance.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by automated tests?

If you mean unit/functional/integration tests, then you should have those in place before you upgrade to Rails 3.1. They will be very helpful in finding where things break during the upgrade, and when they all pass you can have some degree of confidence that your application works again.

If by automated tests, you mean something more high level, like UI testing (which is what I interpret it as), I would suggest either [Watir](http://watir.com/) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). Tests like those should still function and wouldn't be affected by the underlying implementation (whether it's Rails 3.0.10 or 3.1). As long as the app still works those tests would still work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all tests must be written before code.

I suggest cover you application by tests and then switch to Rails 3.1 in your case.

I prefer use [rspec](http://rspec.info/) and [cucumber](http://cukes.info/) together.
This is two different approach of testing [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)(rspec) and [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development)(cucumber).

Comment: I use rspec as well, but I'll point out that tests — while they *should* be written before you write your actual code (following test-driven development) — they don't *have* to be. It's easiest to do the former, but tests after the fact are better than no tests at all.

Comment: @Benjamin Kreeger wrong point, because you can't be sure that you wrote right tests. If you follow TDD link you will see how it should be. Your method isn't TDD

Comment: I was really only pointing out the difference between following TDD and not doing so. Writing tests ≠ TDD.